# Does the EFCore migration locks entire schema?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

In our project, we handle DB (Postgres) migrations using EFCore migrations (but we write them ourselves, they are not autogenerated). Example script:

```
// it is making column nullable
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "discount_type",
    table: some_table_name,
    nullable: true,
    schema: "some_schema");

// it is making column nullable
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
    name: "discount_value",
    table: some_table_name,
    nullable: true,
    schema: "some_schema");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "some_key_name_fk",
    table: some_table_name,
    column: "code_id",
    schema: "some_schema",
    principalTable: some_table_name_2,
    principalColumn: "id",
    principalSchema: "some_schema",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "description_english",
    table: some_table_name,
    schema: Constants.Schema);

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "description_german",
    table: some_table_name,
    schema: "some_schema");
```

We found that during the migration, our service become unresponsive for few minutes. All queries (`SELECT` queries in majority) where giving timeout. 100% requests failed. Please note that `some_table_name` table has over 120 million records.

My question is if EFCore migration somehow locks the entire DB schema, even preventing it from reading data? If 'yes' - how to prevent it?

Comment: No, DDL only locks the _table_ which is being ALTERed, not all tables in the schema. I don't know EF Core but I guess it applies each of those steps as a separate ALTER TABLE statement. I don't understand the syntax but if there are some changes that require a rewrite of the table (e.g. a data type change from `integer` to `decimal`) then it would be way more efficient to do all changes in a single ALTER statement rather than multiple ones (except for the creation of the foreign key obviously)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added clarification to the question, saying that script just made columns nullable (no change of a data type).